# application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8-beta6

After installing Xcode 8 beta 6, I'm getting a warning saying:

> Instance method 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

in my App Delegate.

There are 2 suggested fixits to silence the warning:

1. Mark the method as private
2. Add @nonobjc to the method

Doing either silences the warning. But why does this need to be done?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### iOS 12 SDK Update

In the iOS 12 SDK (that ships with Xcode 10), `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey` [has now been renamed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application?changes=latest_minor) to the nested type `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey`, so you'll want:

```
func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
    // ...
}
```

---

#### iOS 10 and 11 SDKs (Xcode 8 and 9)

This warning is due to the fact that the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` parameter of the [`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) delegate method is now bridged to Swift as a `[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?`, rather than an `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`.

Therefore you'll need to update your implementation to reflect this change:

```
func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
    // ...
}
```

Note that neither of Xcode's suggested fixes will actually fix the problem, they'll only conceal your implementation of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` from Objective-C – meaning that it'll never actually get called.

Comment: Yes, as new implementation doesn't get options parameter, as well as doesn't return Boolean from latest SDK

Comment: The fix suggested here using `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey` doesn't suppress the warning in my project in Xcode 8 beta 6 either, so currently I have to live with that warning.

Comment: @CodePlumber Hmm interesting, it's working fine for me in Xcode 8 beta 6 – are you sure your `launchOptions` argument is a `[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?`? (It's possible you may have forgotten to change `AnyObject` to `Any`). Also check you're not missing the omitted external argument label for the `application` parameter (if in doubt, you can copy and paste the signature from the answer). If it's still not working, you may want to try cleaning your build folder.

Comment: You're right, Hamish! It should be `Any` not `AnyObject`.

Comment: I had followed the Xcode suggested fixes and then couldn't figure out why code in didFinishLaunching wasn't running. Thank you for this!!

Comment: The *many* changes required to maintain code between subsequent versions of Xcode are pure madness IMHO! Apple should improve its game, for this causes a lot of effort.

Answer (score 3):

> the first parameter passed into the function no longer has an external name. This is really just a minor detail since you don’t call this method directly, and it’s a quick fix to make the compiler happy. You can either manually edit that first parameter name to _, or just let Xcode handle this for you.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

or the New Syntax

```
func application(_ application:UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool // or remove = nil and try
```

you can get the latest Documentation from [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and sample link in [here](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2016/07/11/swift-3-developer-preview/)

Comment: I just realised that when I posted the question, the underscore did not show up, so i have edited it. The method signature has always had the _. This warning only showed up on Xcode 8 beta 6. It was not there in previous betas of Xcode 8

Comment: Yeah, those warning sometimes more confuse than help