# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException - Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift3, sigabrt, nsexception, xcode8-beta6

in the last weeks i updated my Xcode until the last beta, Xcode 8 beta 6. Before these upgrades all worked well, but now i am getting some problems.
I have a tab bar application. When I tap on the last tab, I get the Error Sigabrt and the console says `Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`
My code is the following:

[image]

How can I fix this bug?
Thanks everybody for helping!

Comment: Retype the method `applicationDidFinishLaunching...` using code completion  to get new syntax or look it up in the documentation. To get more information about the exception set the exception breakpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [application(\_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' nearly matches optional requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972440/application-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-nearly-matches-optional-requireme)